# Dell NX3330 installing Windows Server OS?

Tags: windows, dell-poweredge, network-attached-storage, dell-powervault

Recently my company upgraded our storage system and now we have a few old Dell Power Vault NX3330 sitting around not being used.

So I heard that it is possible to install the full windows server OS onto these windows storage server machine, as they are essentially the same hardware as the power edge server.

I am just wondering if anyone know what's the step to achieve that?  I Would really love to repurpose these machine for something else so I don't have to throw them away.

Answer (score 1):

This should be *technically* possible, since they usually run Windows Storage Server, thus they are definitely compatible with a full Windows Server installation; however, this would be a completely unsupported configuration, and is thus off-topic here.

The actual steps to install a different OS on them would depend on which I/O devices are available on the units; if they have a video port and some USB ports, this should be pretty easy. If they don't, it could get *tricky*.

Comment: Not entirely useful responds, but thanks for your comments anyway. I have seen plenty of other questions similar to this for other system, so not exactly uncommon type of questions.